# set entire group to NaN if containing a single NaN and combine columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
a  b  c    d
0  1  nan  1
0  2  2    nan     
0  2  3    4
1  3  1    nan
1  1  nan  3
1  1  2    3
1  1  2    4
```

I need to groub by a and b and then if c or d contains 1 or more nan's within groups I want the entire group in the specific column to be nan:

```
a  b  c    d
0  1  nan  1
0  2  2    nan     
0  2  3    nan
1  3  1    nan
1  1  nan  3
1  1  nan  3
1  1  nan  4
```

and then combine c and d that there is no nan's anymore

```
a  b  c    d    e
0  1  nan  1    1
0  2  2    nan  2   
0  2  3    nan  3
1  3  1    nan  1
1  1  nan  3    3
1  1  nan  3    3
1  1  nan  4    4
```

Answer (score 4):

You will want to check each group for whether it is nan and then set the appropriate value (nan or existing value) and then use `combine_first()` to combine the columns.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
a b c d
0 1 nan 1
0 2 2 nan
0 2 3 4
1 3 1 nan
1 1 nan 3
1 1 2 3
1 1 2 4
"""), sep=' ')

for col in ['c', 'd']:
    df[col] = df.groupby(['a','b'])[col].transform(lambda x: np.nan if any(x.isna()) else x)

df['e'] = df['c'].combine_first(df['d'])
df
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   NaN 1.0 1.0
1   0   2   2.0 NaN 2.0
2   0   2   3.0 NaN 3.0
3   1   3   1.0 NaN 1.0
4   1   1   NaN 3.0 3.0
5   1   1   NaN 3.0 3.0
6   1   1   NaN 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. The 'for' is necessary? since it's a huge df.

Comment: It's just iterating over your two columns. Shouldn't matter how many rows you have. It would be the same as just writing 2 lines with hardcoded column names